# How does the $\partial _{\mu} (\frac{\partial L}{\partial [\partial _{\mu} \phi]})$ term expand into a sum?

Tags: special-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, metric-tensor, differentiation, covariance

From *QFT Demystified* page 31:

[image]

This term is from the Euler-Lagrange equation of a scalar field. How does this expand into a sum?

Do we just sum over all $\mu$ from $\mu =0$ to 3, or are we supposed to subtract the spatial terms in the expanded sum?

I believe it should just be a simple sum. This is because the action didn't differentiate between space and time derivatives at all (The Lagrangian being $L(\phi, \partial _{\mu} \phi)$. So it doesn't make sense for the spatial terms to end up with a minus sign in the Euler Lagrange equation. However, the book I'm reading says the expanded sum has minus signs for the spatial terms.

In general, when do we simply sum over repeated indices and when do we have to use minus signs? The expansion of $\partial ^{\mu} \partial_ {\mu} \phi$ has minus signs. But many other times, we just do a simple sum over repeated indices.

Comment: It should be all plus signs.

Comment: These sorts of books aren’t very trustworthy… in general, you shouldn’t use an introductory book if it hasn’t been thoroughly tested by real students before publication.

Comment: @knzhou This demystified series is really popular. Lots of people advised this book for a layman introduction. Still can't believe such an error made it in.

Comment: This particular error happens literally all the time for some reason, even in more reputable textbooks. I strongly suspect it comes from professors who haven't had to do real calculations by themselves in a long time...

Comment: @Zack That makes me feel loads better about the idiotic calculations I make. Still it's weird that this error didn't get caught during the publishing process.

Comment: It happens all the time unfortunately, especially in advanced textbooks where errors can be more subtle and the experts don’t have time to carefully check textbooks. People are human, books contain many equations, and editors have finite time. If you continue into research, you’ll find typos even in published and well-cited papers. The takeaway is that you shouldn’t read physics lazily, you have to be vigilant as you go through, and check multiple sources against each other if possible.

Comment: The demystified series is just fine, as long as you use it as a purely conceptual introduction. You should just glance at the shape of each equation, or even skip them all. If you’re reading so closely that you can detect the many sign errors, then of course you’ll run into trouble…

Comment: That is what happens when the author does not submit his manuscript to proofreading. Wrong signs may appear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the second equation with the spatial minus signs is simply wrong. All signs should be plus. There *are* minus signs in the wave equation, of course, but these come from minus signs in the *Lagrangian density*:
$$
L= \frac 12 \partial^\mu \phi \partial_\mu\phi\\= \frac 12 g^{\mu\nu} \partial_\nu \phi \partial_\mu\phi\\= \frac 12 [(\partial_t \phi)^2 - (\partial_x \phi)^2 -(\partial_y \phi)^2 -(\partial_z \phi)^2].
$$

Answer (score 2):

It should be all plus signs.

1. It's a straightforward short calculation to derive the correct field-theoretic [Euler-Lagrange (EL) equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation).
2. The calculation can be carried out for any (first-order) local action functional without knowing details about the specific physical theory at hand, such as, whether or not the theory contains a metric and/or the signature of spacetime. For this reason alone, the Minkowski metric cannot be there.
3. Another argument is to analyze the tensorial properties of the EL equations, i.e. a lower index in the "denominator" transforms as an upper index.

Answer (score 1):

It can get a bit confusing but just remember that
$$A_\mu B^\mu = \sum_\mu A_\mu B^\mu$$ The Einstein summnation shorthand has nothing in principle to do with special relativity, the only reason the metric gets involved is because we transform 4-vectors to 4-covectors like
$$A\cdot B=g_{\mu\nu}A^\mu B^\nu = (g_{\mu\nu}A^\mu)B^\nu = A_\nu B^\nu$$
where $A$ and $B$ are 4-vectors.
In other words $$A_0 = -A^0$$ which is where the minus sign comes from.